# AJAX / PHP shopping cart, not working properly

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm having some problems with, building a shopping cart.

Instead of clicking on the add button multiple times to change the quantity, I want to change it directly in an input. It works well, but when you're deleting one of the items in the cart, the price of all the other items, will be set to zero, and I have no clue why this is happening.

The cart I'm using, is PHP/SQL and AJAX.

This is my code so far:

**PHP:**

```
<?php

// This document contains the AJAX generated for the building-cart
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Clear Cache and include config.php
include("includes/config.php");
// Start Session
session_start();
?>
<?php

$product_id = $_GET['id']; //the product id from the URL 
$action = $_GET['action']; //the action from the URL
$quantity = $_GET['quantity']; //the action from the URL 

// if there is an product_id and that product_id doesn't exist display an error message
if($product_id && !productExists($product_id)) {
    die("Error. Product Doesn't Exist");
}

// decide what to do 
switch($action) {

    case "add":

    //add one to the quantity of the product with id $product_id 
    if($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] < 1) { $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]++; }

    break;

    case "remove":
        $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]--; //remove one from the quantity of the product with id $product_id 
        if($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] == 0) unset($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]); //if the quantity is zero, remove it completely (using the 'unset' function) - otherwise is will show zero, then -1, -2 etc when the user keeps removing items. 
    break;

    case "empty":
        unset($_SESSION['cart']); //unset the whole cart, i.e. empty the cart. 
    break;

}

?>
<?php 

//if the cart isn't empty show the cart
if($_SESSION['cart']) {

    echo '<ul id="cart-items">'."\n";

    //iterate through the cart, the $product_id is the key and $quantity is the value
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product_id => $quantity) { 

        //get the name, description and price from the database - this will depend on your database implementation.
        //use sprintf to make sure that $product_id is inserted into the query as a number - to prevent SQL injection
         $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM single_partners WHERE single_id = $product_id");

        //Only display the row if there is a product (though there should always be as we have already checked)
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            if($test = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                $partner_id = $test['partner_id'];
                $partner_price = $test['price'];

                $line_cost = $partner_price * quantity; //work out the line cost
                $total = $total + $line_cost; //add to the total cost
            }   

            // Get partner name
            $get_partner_name = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM partners WHERE partner_id='$partner_id'");
            if($partner_name = mysql_fetch_array($get_partner_name)) {

                $name = $partner_name['name'];
                $logo = $partner_name['logo'];
                $type = $partner_name['type'];
                $logo_dir = "media/partners/build/color/";

            }

            echo '<li>'."\n";
            echo '<div class="logo" style="background-image: url('.$logo_dir.$logo.')">'."\n";
            echo '</div>'."\n";
            echo '<div class="details">'."\n";
            echo '<span class="name">'.$name.'</span>'."\n";
            echo '<span class="details">Detaljer</span>'."\n";
            echo '</div>'."\n";
            echo '<div class="price"><input name="partner" type="hidden" value="'.$product_id.'" /><span class="remove-button"></span>'."\n";
            echo '<span class="price">'.number_format((float)$line_cost, 2, ',', '').'</span>'."\n";
            echo '</div>'."\n";
            echo '</li>'."\n";
        }
    }
    echo '<div class="footer">'."\n";
    echo '<span class="empty-button">Tøm</span>'."\n";
    echo '<span class="total-price">'.number_format((float)$total, 2, ',', '').'</span>'."\n";
    echo '</div>'."\n";
    //show the total
//    echo "<tr>";
//    echo "<td colspan=\"2\" align=\"right\">Total</td>";
//    echo "<td align=\"right\">$total</td>";
//    echo "</tr>";
//
//    //show the empty cart link - which links to this page, but with an action of empty. A simple bit of javascript in the onlick event of the link asks the user for confirmation
//    echo "<tr>";
//    echo "<td colspan=\"3\" align=\"right\"><a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?action=empty\" onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure?');\">Empty Cart</a></td>";
//    echo "</tr>"; 
    echo '</ul>'."\n";



}else{
//otherwise tell the user they have no items in their cart
    //echo "You have no items in your shopping cart.";

}

//function to check if a product exists
function productExists($product_id) {
    //use sprintf to make sure that $product_id is inserted into the query as a number - to prevent SQL injection
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM single_partners WHERE single_id = $product_id");

    return mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0;
}
?>
```

**AJAX:**

```
// Load building cart, when adding items
$(document).on('click', 'input[type=button].add-button', function() {

    // AJAX - Define data to send
    var actiontype = "add";
        productid = $('input[name="address"]').val();
        quantity = $('input[name="qun"]').val();
    var data = "action="+ actiontype + "&id="+ productid + "&quantity="+ quantity;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'buildingcart.php',
        data: data,
        success:function(result) {  
            // Show result
            $('#building-cart .content').html(result);
        }
    });
});

// Load building cart, when adding items
$(document).on('click', '.remove-button', function() {

    // AJAX - Define data to send
    var actiontype = "remove";
        productid = $(this).parent().find('input[name="partner"]').val();

    var data = "action="+ actiontype + "&id="+ productid;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'buildingcart.php',
        data: data,
        success:function(result) {  
            // Show result
            $('#building-cart .content').html(result);
        }
    });
});

// Load building cart, when adding items
$(document).on('click', '.empty-button', function() {

    // AJAX - Define data to send
    var actiontype = "empty";

    var data = "action="+ actiontype;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'buildingcart.php',
        data: data,
        success:function(result) {  
            // Show result
            $('#building-cart .content').html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

I tried changing

`foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product_id => $quantity)`

to

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product_id)
```

with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

you forgot a $ sign at this line

$line_cost = $partner_price * quantity; //work out the line cost

should be

$line_cost = $partner_price * $quantity; //work out the line cost

EDIT:
also you might want to optimize your code to only make one sql select like this:

```
//if the cart isn't empty show the cart
if($_SESSION['cart']) {
    echo '<ul id="cart-items">'."\n";

    $productIds = implode(",", array_keys($_SESSION['cart']));

    $sql = "
        SELECT
            single_partners.single_id AS product_id,
            single_partners.partner_id,
            single_partners.price,
            partners.name,
            partners.logo,
            partners.type

        FROM single_partners
        INNER JOIN partners
            ON partners.partner_id = single_partners.partner_id
        WHERE single_id IN ({$productIds})
    ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $logo_dir = "media/partners/build/color/";
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $product_id = $row['product_id'];
            $partner_id = $row['partner_id'];
            $partner_price = $row['price'];
            $name = $row['name'];   
            $logo = $row['logo'];
            $type = $row['type'];
            $quantity = $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id];

            $line_cost = $partner_price * $quantity; //work out the line cost
            $total = $total + $line_cost; //add to the total cost        

            echo '<li>'."\n";
            echo '<div class="logo" style="background-image: url('.$logo_dir.$logo.')">'."\n";
            echo '</div>'."\n";
            echo '<div class="details">'."\n";
            echo '<span class="name">'.$name.'</span>'."\n";
            echo '<span class="details">Detaljer</span>'."\n";
            echo '</div>'."\n";
            echo '<div class="price"><input name="partner" type="hidden" value="'.$product_id.'" /><span class="remove-button"></span>'."\n";
            echo '<span class="price">'.number_format((float)$line_cost, 2, ',', '').'</span>'."\n";
            echo '</div>'."\n";
            echo '</li>'."\n";
        }
    }

    echo '</ul>'."\n";
}
else{
    //otherwise tell the user they have no items in their cart
    //echo "You have no items in your shopping cart.";
}
```

Comment: Now you can delete an item, without all the rest are being set to zero, but it also ignore the quantity of the product. If I for example, have a product which cost 100, and I set the quantity/amount to 5, it still only display 100 and not 500.

Comment: You will need to write a case "update" in your switch. You will need to implement that functionality to make sure price reflects quantity wherever needed.

Comment: The quantities/amounts of each items, are still being set to zero if I remove one of the items

Comment: this time I have no idea why. try setting error reporting to on for that page to see any warnings/notices. to do that put this on the first line in php file: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', true);`